# how to route this in mvc web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this requirement to map the url

```
api/v1/Contact/12/tags
```

in the above url the `Contact` is the controller, and `12` is the contactId and `tags` is the action is want to be called.

The method is like this

```
[HttpGet]
public List<TagModel> Tags([FromUri]int contactId)
```

I have did like this

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "RouteForHandlingTags",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
                );

I am getting the error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI http://localhost:4837/api/v1/contact/12/tags"
```

I have tried

```
[HttpGet]
public List<TagModel> Tags(int contactId)
```

and

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "RouteForHandlingTags",
                    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
                    );
```

But all are giving the same error. But when I do a call like this

```
api/v1/Contact/12/tags?contactid=12
```

everything works fine. But this is not what I want. The contactId is specified after contact. Can anyone please tell me how to route this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter names in your action and route must match.
You can either change your action to:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<TagModel> Tags(int id)
```

Or change your route to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RouteForHandlingTags",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{contactId}/{action}",
    defaults: new { },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
    );
```

Note: you do not need [FromUri] with a primitive type like an int.

Comment: Damn it! Just a little mistake. Thanks.